# GmailApp.sendEmail and MailApp.sendEmail cannot sent to recipients with +

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script

I noticed that GmailApp.sendEmail as well as MailApp.sendEmail is not able to send emails if the recipient email contains a '+' sign.

[Gmail supports dynamic alias by using '+' in emails like this: username+anything@gmail.com](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/12096?hl=en), however both these classes are not able to send mails to such addresses.

For example, this works:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail('username@gmail.com', 'subject', 'body');
MailApp.sendEmail('username@gmail.com', 'subject', 'body');
```

...while this doesn't:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail('username+anything@gmail.com', 'subject', 'body');
MailApp.sendEmail('username+anything@gmail.com', 'subject', 'body');
```

Has anyone come across this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an issue. I was trying to send to self with + in the email and these were not showing up in Inbox. These showed up only in Send folder which created this confusion.